# Error assigning lambda to functional interface variable: inherited abstract method must be implemented. Why?

Tags: java, functional-interface, lambda

I implemented the functional interface, using the functional method in a lambda function. Everything works fine except I get an error that this inherited abstract method (in my case, the functional method) must be implemented. And here I'm confused. I used the lambda function to implement this functional method. Why should I again implement the method?
How is the implementation of functional methods done correctly?

Here is my code:

```java
interface MyFunction {
    int getValue(int num);
}
class Factorial implements MyFunction {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        MyFunction myFactorialFunc = (num) -> {
            int fact = 1;
            for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
                fact = i * fact;
            }
            return fact;
        };
        System.out.println(myFactorialFunc.getValue(7));
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `implements MyFunction`. Your class does not implement your interface. It's using the interface inside a method. That's not the same thing.

Comment: @khelwood  so that means the use of functional Interface is within the method ?

Comment: @Ad.Kh Thanks for contributing a suggested edit! For as long as your are under 2k rep, when you suggest edits, please improve the entire post. I have improved your edit. Please study the improvement and learn from it how to improve future posts which you edit. You can see [ask] for guidance on what a good question post is like. Again, thanks for your contribution. Keep it up. Just make sure to _make the most_ of your contributions as good etiquette to the reviewers reviewing your edits. Ie. Improve the whole post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you must have heard from somewhere that "you can implement single-method interfaces with a lambda expression!" and proceeded to try it out by writing this code, all the while misunderstanding what is meant by that.

Lambda expressions *doesn't* actually allow you to write `class MyClass implements SomeInterface` without declaring the required method. As far as the compiler is concerned, `Factorial` only has a `main` method declared, and no `getValue` method, so it doesn't implement the `MyFunction` interface.

Your code does demonstrate "you can implement single-method interfaces with a lambda expression" though. Here in the `main` method, you assigned a lambda expression to a variable of type `MyFunction`:

```
MyFunction myFactorialFunc = (num) -> {
    int fact = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
        fact = i * fact;
    }
    return fact;
};
```

Normally, you have to put *an implementation of* `MyFunction` on the right-hand side of `=`, don't you? But now, you can just use a lambda expression! This is because the signature of the lambda expression matches the signature of the single method in the interface, so the compiler goes "yeah, that's fine, I'll just use this as the implementation of that method".

Answer (score 0):

You defined your `Factorial` class to implement `MyFunction`, but it doesn't implement the method of that interface (`int getValue(int num);`).

The `MyFunction` instance implemented within your `main` using a lambda expression doesn't implement that interface for your `Factorial` class.

Just change it to:

```
class Factorial {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        MyFunction myFactorialFunc = (num) -> {
            int fact = 1;
            for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
                fact = i * fact;
            }
            return fact;
        };
        System.out.println(myFactorialFunc.getValue(7));
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so that's how functional interfaces work. They are used for specific implementations within the method but they are not implemented for the whole class (in this case)